# Calculate average for preceding multiple periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to calculate the average for the preceding 4 quarters for the next quarter grouped by claim type. I have found an answer but it doesn't seem compatible with SQL Server 2008 which I am currently using. I can't seem to find the same functions or solutions for SQL Server 2008.

It seems that you can not order by or use `rows between` with the `over function` in my version.

Can someone please assist me to get the same functionality for SQL Server 2008?

I want to get the average for 4 preceding quarters for the column `[Total Paid]`

```
SELECT 
    [PolicyNo] AS [PolicyNo],
    [Quarter] AS [Quarter],
    [Claim Grouping] AS [Claim Grouping],
    [Year] AS [Year],
    [Total Claim] AS [Total Claim],
    AVG([Total Claim]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Claim Grouping] ORDER BY [Year], [Quarter]
                             ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [4QuarterAverage]
FROM 
    BaseTable
```

An added column `4QuarterAverage` with the average of the `4 preceding quarters` for `[Total Paid]`

Comment: If `ORDER BY [Year], [Quarter]` is not a deterministic sort, which i am assuming it is you can still get non deterministic ("random") avg values within that "data frame (working window)" on every run ... Ideally you want to add a extra column in the `ORDER BY` that has a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key to make the value deterministic  always on every run..

Comment: Thanks, I'll add [PolicyNo] to the ORDER BY clause

Comment: But that isn't the main problem I am having - It gives me errors when running the code as is because of the version I am using. The error says : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 doesn't support the `ROWS BETWEEN` syntax.  You'll need to find a workaround.  Let me see if I can dig something up.

Comment: Thanks, I also saw that as the problem and have been trying to find a way around for a while but haven't found anything yet. I also tried using LAG() but that is also not compatible with  SQL Server 2008

Comment: O you are using SQL Server 2008.. Window functions could be "simply" emulated as a corelated subquery aswell but the `ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` makes it more tricky..  Can you provide a working example  https://dbfiddle.uk/ on a more modern SQL Server ?

Comment: It's currently not working because of the ROWS BETWEEN Function - But the data basically is group by policyNo, for every quarter in a year (4 Years) , for every claim grouping (Fire, Other, Pipes and Water, Theft and Weather). In essence their is 20 rows by PolicyNo per Year

Comment: Here's a quick fiddle you can use as an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/25da1/22.  I'll post a solution a little later.

Comment: @HelenaViljoen SQL Server 2008 is 11 years old an [out of support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2/) with even extended (ie paid) support over. You should be migrating to something fresher already. As for this query, how much data is there? You could the data to a SQL Server 2017 Express instance for reporting. From a support standpoint, this would be better. Given the perf improvements it could also be *faster*, especially if you take advantage of columnstores

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this with a correlated subquery or `apply`:

```
SELECT bt.*, bt2.[4QuarterAverage]
FROM BaseTabel bt OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT AVG(bt2.[Total Claim]) as [4QuarterAverage]
      FROM (SELECT TOP (4) bt2.*
            FROM BaseTabel bt2
            WHERE (bt2.YEAR < bt.YEAR OR
                   (bt2.YEAR = bt.YEAR AND bt2.Quarter <= bt.Quarter)
                  )
            ORDER BY bt2.YEAR DESC, bt2.Quarter DESC
           ) bt2
      ) bt2;
```

Comment: Thank You! I am getting a syntax error when trying to implement this solution - I can't seem to figure out why as everything seems to be in order : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near ')'. It is at the last line

Comment: @HelenaViljoen . . . It was the second to last `)`.  The table alias was missing.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It's messy, but here's another solution:

```sql
WITH cte([PolicyNo], [Quarter], [Claim Grouping], [Year], [Total Claim], [RowNum]) AS (
  SELECT 
    [PolicyNo], [Quarter], [Claim Grouping], [Year], [Total Claim],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      PARTITION BY [Claim Grouping] ORDER BY [Year], [Quarter] -- Assign "row numbers"
    ) AS [RowNum]
  FROM BaseTabel
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
  src.[PolicyNo], src.[Quarter], src.[Claim Grouping], src.[Year], src.[Total Claim],
  AVG(src.[Total_Claim_prev]) OVER(
    PARTITION BY [Claim Grouping], src.[rownum]
  ) AS [4QuarterAverage]
FROM (
  SELECT 
    cte.[rownum],
    cte.[PolicyNo], 
    cte.[Year], 
    cte.[Quarter], 
    cte.[Claim Grouping],
    cte.[Total Claim], 
    cte2.[total claim] AS [Total_Claim_prev]
  FROM cte
  LEFT JOIN cte AS cte2 ON cte.[Claim Grouping] = cte2.[Claim Grouping]
    AND cte2.[RowNum] BETWEEN cte.[RowNum] - 4 AND cte.[RowNum] - 1 -- Get 4 previous rows
) src
```

Your post says you want the average for the four preceding quarters, but your initial query gives the average of the three preceding quarters (`THREE PRECEDING`) and the current one (`CURRENT ROW`).

This query will give you the average of the four preceding quarters, excluding the current one.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/47ad83/2)

Comment: Thanks @ravioli, This seem to have done the trick! It's working perfectly now!